# Trying to write a rake task that will fail if the database exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Given that rake db:drop does not fail if it can't drop the database, I am trying to find a rake task that will fail if the database is still there.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try dropping the database through SQL and check the result of query. If the query returns something like "Database xxx does not exist" or may be a special code like -1, then you fail the Rake task.